# Converting binary to hexadecimal

Tags: javascript

I am converting binary to hexadecimal but the code below returns a wrong answer:

```
var number = 1011;
var hexa = parseInt(number, 2).toString(16);
return hexa;
```

This returns `b` but it should have to be return `B`. What is the problem?

Comment: `parseInt(number , 2).toString(16).toUpperCase();`

Comment: Hexadecimal can be lowercase

Comment: Thanks Arun and Nick.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just add `toUpperCase()`:

```
var hexa = parseInt(number, 2).toString(16).toUpperCase();
```

Comment: what if it is supposed to be a lowercase and then gets turned into the uppercase?

Comment: Note that you might lose information when converting big numbers this way, due to the limited precision of integers. If you need a higher level of precision, this solution leveraging `BigInt` might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55681265/3366464

Comment: @GertjanFranken 100% true.

Answer (score 21):

'b' *is* correct. Hexadecimal doesn't specify letter case, and many write hex strings with lower-case letters.