# hex-to-binary in typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, hex

this function is what [hex-to-binary](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hex-to-binary) package uses. since it does not have types file and even declaring in decs.t.ts does not work, i tried to implement in typescript:

```
const lookup: Lookup = {
  "0": "0000",
  "1": "0001",
  "2": "0010",
  "3": "0011",
  "4": "0100",
  "5": "0101",
  "6": "0110",
  "7": "0111",
  "8": "1000",
  "9": "1001",
  a: "1010",
  b: "1011",
  c: "1100",
  d: "1101",
  e: "1110",
  f: "1111",
  A: "1010",
  B: "1011",
  C: "1100",
  D: "1101",
  E: "1110",
  F: "1111",
};

export function hexToBinary(s:string) {
  let ret = "";
  for (let i = 0, len = s.length; i < len; i++) {
    ret += lookup[s[i]];
  }
  return ret;
}
```

so we pass a string to hexToBinary(s:string). Specifically this string has to have only binary characters since I could not figure out how to define it, I pass `s:string` because `s.length` will be defined.

`lookup[s[i]]` is giving this error: "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ 0: string; 1: string; 2: string; 3: string; 4: string; 5: string; 6: string; 7: string; 8: string; 9: string; a: string; b: string; c: string; d: string; e: string; f: string; A: string; B: string; C: string; D: string; E: string; F: string; }'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ 0: string; 1: string; 2: string; 3: string; 4: string; 5: string; 6: string; 7: string; 8: string; 9: string; a: string; b: string; c: string; d: string; e: string; f: string; A: string; B: string; C: string; D: string; E: string; F: string; }'"

So typescript is recognizing "lookup" as array. It does not understand that it is a computed property.

I defined an interface for lookup object:

```
interface Lookup {
  "0"?: string;
  "1"?: string;
  "2"?: string;
  "3"?: string;
  "4"?: string;
  "5"?: string;
  "6"?: string;
  "7"?: string;
  "8"?: string;
  "9"?: string;
  a?: string;
  b?: string;
  c?: string;
  d?: string;
  e?: string;
  f?: string;
  A?: string;
  B?: string;
  C?: string;
  D?: string;
  E?: string;
  F?: string;
}
```

But this time i got this error:
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Lookup'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Lookup'.ts(7053)

Answer (score 0):

From running your code on the typescript playground, the only error I see is that `Lookup` is not defined. Considering that you are declaring an object, if you want to assign an interface to it (like `Lookup`), you'll have to mention each and every property in the interface. Trust me, you **do not want to do this**.

Regarding the question at hand, i am not able to understand the approach you are trying to take. The result can be achieved using something way simpler.

```js
const binary = parseInt("AB5",16).toString(2)
console.log(binary)
```

[image: Example]

---

The following answers can be taken for reference:

- [Converting binary to hexadecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36562953/converting-binary-to-hexadecimal/36562977)
- [Converting large numbers from binary to decimal and back in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39334494/converting-large-numbers-from-binary-to-decimal-and-back-in-javascript/55681265#55681265)
- [JavaScript: Need functions to convert a string containing binary to hex, then convert back to binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204912/javascript-need-functions-to-convert-a-string-containing-binary-to-hex-then-co)

Answer (score 0):

Declare `lookup` as a `Record<string, string>` (object mappings strings to strings) instead to avoid key errors:

```
const lookup: Record<string, string> = {
    // lookup goes here
};

// rest of code
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBANiEBrArgBwFwwEoFNQBOAJgDzQECWYA5gDQzlXUB8MAvDAN4BQMMARAAZ+WIYPH9avAQEYRA8YLlS+-AEzyxM4SoEBmTeJnLp-ACyHtO0wFZLSyaYBsl7Y9UB2VydUAOTVbWqgCcAUbuMACGotpuugBGMUo+MMAxVhFE6Q66uOlx0gBm+SkAgkkFfABCFSkAwtlBMAAi2SkAovlNAGIljgC+ANzc3LgAHmggBLCFKGDAUBTgMAAW4wAqIFVUkQQAngAUEFiMNACUXNJwuLAEN+wC-MN8hVMwB9ewFA+C9NdgDwgADp-tQoCtBjBviR4LgwJCKABqREXHh8Ph3WCIjgIZDoADaEHxFAAuiTnjB+tJMSgCADMcN+kA)